# Suppress time field in Crystal Report Footer

Tags: sql, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report - Version 8.5. In report footer, I have a field which is time field (format will be "00:00"). I need it to suppress, if the time is "00:00", but not if its anything else like "9:30" or "15:00" etc.

Any suggestions, because I've already tried everything else like suppress if ctime(field) = ctime("00:00"). Any other suggestions?. I Cannot change the output of the sql query.

Comment: have you tried same formula by placing in detail? because report footer will show the last record in this case check whether you are getting "00:00" in report footer

Comment: What is Sql DataType of `field` column. If it's date/time then above suppress condition should work. Just for a test, have you tried using `TimeValue()` instead of `cTime()`

Comment: @haraman the sqldatatype is 'time without time zone'. Timevalue didnt work. formula shows no error but supression doesn't occur.

Comment: If datatype is time then why are you again converting to time during comparision? What is the format in database hh:mm:ss or hh:mm

Comment: that was just one of the options i tried. Not the only one. I figured maybe crystal had problems recognizing the data and hence reconverted it. in database it is hh:mm:ss...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click the `Time` field
2. Select `Format Field...`
3. Select the `Common` tab
4. Click the <kbd>x+2</kbd> button to the right of the `Suppress` checkbox.
5. Enter the following text: `CurrentFieldValue=Time(0,0,0)`

Comment: Just tried this and it works. However in my case i spent considerable amount of time looking up the query and duplicating it so that for this particular report it outputs empty values for that particular time as i couldn't wait too long to get it done. Hopefully it helps future souls :)